# SQL insertion protection using RMySQL

Tags: mysql, r, rmysql

I am trying to implement SQL insertion protection to SQL select statements using `RMySQL`. I have been trying to prepend an escape character (i.e. a backslash) in front of each risk character - i.e. a quote (" or ') or backslash (\). I am using the RMySQL function, `dbEscapeStrings` which appears to be similar to PHP's `mysql_real_escape_string` function.

I suspect I am missing something very obvious but, as MySQL requires character strings in the WHERE statement to be enclosed by quotes, using `dbEscapeStrings` to apply escape characters to quotes in the select statement is throwing an error blocking all string queries, not just the injection attacks. For example,

```
user <- "'peter'"
tmp <- sprintf("select * from users where username = %s", user)
sql <- dbEscapeStrings(con, tmp)
dbGetQuery(con, sql)
```

dbEscapeStrings inserts a double backslash in front of each quote (i.e. the sql variable produced is *"select * from users where username = \\'peter\\'"*) which throws a syntax error on the MySQL server when `dbGetQuery` is run.

Any suggestions appreciated on how to get the above to work or implement an alternative SQL insertion protection using RMySQL? Does RMySQL provide for using prepared statements that could prevent insertion attacks?

Comment: try `mysqlExecStatement(con, tmp, user)`, followed by `mysqlFetch(dbListResults(con)[[1]])`. I am suggesting this based on what i do with RPostgreSQL.

Comment: Thanks @Alex for the advice on the prepared statement. It works well. I also worked out a solution for the escape character - I knew I was missing something simple - apply the `dbEscapeStrings` to "user", not "tmp" and before adding the single quotes to "user".

Comment: @Alex I strongly recommend that you use the standard db generics - `mysqlExecStatement()` should never have been exported and will be doing away in the next version

Comment: Thanks. What are standard db generics?

Answer (score 3):

The safest (and easiest) way would be to use a parameterised query (this isn't available on the CRAN release, but is in the dev version)

```
dbGetQuery(myconnection, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?", list(user))
```